# Recalculating other form values: textbox_Leave OR textbox_TextChanged?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, keyboard-events

I am currently working on a WinForms project and have a few text boxes on the form which are used to take user input. Based on the values the user enters, the values for other fields on the form are calculated. Consequently, I am confused which of the two event handlers I should use to perform the calculations: `textbox_Leave` or `textbox_TextChanged`?

Since `textbox_TextChanged` is fired every time the user changes even a character in the textbox, I feel it is very expensive in terms of processor usage, isn't it? On the other hand, `textbox_Leave` is executed only after the user exits from the text box. However, the `TextChanged` event does give a better more responsive experience to the user. But is this experience worth the extra processing hit that we are taking? Will my project be able to function properly on older systems with slower processors if I use `TextChanged`?

Comment: How about you use `TextChanged` in combination with `User pressed enter`? So you only calculate whatever you have to, when the user pressed enter?

Comment: Usually I find that it is better to use binding feature to handle this.

Comment: Depends on how heavy your code behind this is.. a simple calculation shouldn't be a problem, even on older computers

Comment: @Tom Kossman well my code inside the event handler has to take values from a three text boxes. Then perform one arithmatic operation on each of the three text box value to get three resulting values. And then it has to display the minimum of the three in another label on the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is not to process if you don't have to, I usually schedule the "heavy duty stuff", and run it after a while if the **TextBox** has not been changed again. Something like this:

- Textbox changed, cancel previous scheduled updates

  - Schedule update in **x** *msec* (this depends on application type)
- Textbox left, update immediately.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'd say test it with the simple case. If your calculation is not too heavy there may not be a problem in the first place.

If the calculation is really heavy, and you still want the more user-friendly solution, you can implement a throttling mechanism using a timer: in the TextChanged event, start a timer with a Tick handler that starts the calculation after a certain delay; if you receive another TextChanged event before the timer has started, reset the timer. Of course this will involve some synchronization and possibly locking between the timer event and the textchanged event.

Comment: exactly how would u implement this timer?

Comment: @R.S.K start by reading the documentation or google for windows forms timer. Come back and update your question or post a new question if you have a specific problems.

Comment: @jeroenh If we do implement a timer, the real value of TextChanged event is lost isn't it? I mean this event lets the user see the final result as soon as he changes the values in the textbox. So that responsiveness is lost. Moreover, you might confuse or frustrate him bcoz he might not understand what to press or do to see the final result. I guess it would be better to use the TextLeave event rather than implement a timer since here atleast the user will see the result as and when he leaves the text box.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the `Validated` event to perform calculations that depend on input. `TextChanged` will be fired while the user is still entering their value, and may fire while the input is still invalid. If you handle the `Validating` event, you can prevent invalid values from being entered in the text box, and be sure that `Validated` will only be fired when the input is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the user to have real time calculations, I would use textChanged. Having the values only change when the cursor leaves the textBox is likely to be confusing and frustrating for the user.

Without knowing how complex your calculation is, it's hard to speak accurately as to cost. If it's something you're concerned with happening too often, there are a couple possible solutions. If being real-time is not critical, instead of using the "leave" event, provide the user with a "Calculate" button, and also look for an Enter key press. That's much more intuitive to your end user than having to wave the cursor around to get it to calculate.

Another possible solution would be to implement a timer that the textChanged event starts (or resets if it has time on it), and the calculation performed only when it expires. That way a fast typist won't be firing a bunch of calculations in short order, but you can still provide the user experience in near real time without the user having to press anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description of the calculation you are trying to perform I don't think you'll see an issue even on older computers. You're probably underestimating the power of a computer compared to the speed of a user typing something.

Let's say for arguments sake a fast typist can type 100 words per minute. That's about 800 characters, meaning the event will get fired around 13 times per second.

So napkin math tells us we have about 76 milliseconds to perform our calculation and get the result on the screen before the user types another character.

This seems to be a case of [premature optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). 
As a general rule you shouldn't optimise code up front because I'm willing to bet you [ain't gonna need it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it).

That said, I wrote a class once called a DelayedAction which would suit your needs if you do need to optimise. I don't have the code with me right now but a quick google turned up something very similar.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240274/Execute-later-for-delayed-action